# Can't get tabbar app to popToRootViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a programatic tabbar delagate with navbar with a banner view delegate. And for the life of me I can't seem to get the tabs to pop the root view on click. I know I need to use something like [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]; But I don't know where to put it in my app delegate.

```
@implementation AppDelegate {
UITabBarController *_tabBarController;
  }


 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:      (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;

CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

NSMutableArray * viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString * subscriptionListFile = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Subscription.plist"];

NSDictionary * subscriptionList = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:subscriptionListFile];

NSArray * subscriptionFolders = subscriptionList[@"Folders"];

NewsListViewController * newsController = nil;
UINavigationController * newsNavigationController = nil;
BannerViewController * bannervcs = nil;

for (NSDictionary * folderDetails in subscriptionFolders) {

    NSArray * newsItems = folderDetails[@"Items"];
    NSString * folderTitle = folderDetails[@"FolderName"];
    NSString * folderIcon = folderDetails[@"FolderIcon"];
    UIImage * folderIconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:folderIcon];

    newsController = [[NewsListViewController alloc] initWithNewsSourceList:newsItems];
    [newsController setTitle:folderTitle];

    newsNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newsController];
    [newsNavigationController setTitle:folderTitle];

    bannervcs = [[BannerViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:newsNavigationController];
    [bannervcs.tabBarItem setImage:folderIconImage];
    [viewControllers addObject:bannervcs];

  }


_tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
_tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers;

   self.window.rootViewController = _tabBarController;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}



 @end
```

Any idea where I add popToRootViewController? I tried at the end but it doesnt seem to be grabbing any controller...

Comment: where are you adding your navigation controller in your tabBarController?

Comment: My setup is a TabBarController, with Container BannerViewController, with Nav, with TableView. The nav is added right before the VC gets wrapped in banner, so if you NSLOG viewController it returns BannerViewController(1-4), I need a way to get the nav bar inside the selected container controller to poptoroot. My code below can only see BannerView, not the sub nav view.

Comment: what is NewsListViewController ??

Comment: Newslist is a table view, newsnav is a nav, bannervcs is a banner container, tabbar is a tab bar. newsnav is inaccessible because its wrapped in a banner vc.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set something to be your UITabBarControllerDelegate.  Assuming you want to try this out on your AppDelegate, add the line to your method:

```
_tabBarConroller.delegate = self;
```

And then, add this method to your AppDelegate (since it is now also considered an UITabBarControllerDelegate)

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

This is assuming that, regardless of what state the user left the navigation stack on a tab, that tapping another tab always takes the user to the root view controller of the nav stack.

Comment: Yea, doesnt goto top level. I should be able to click the tab item and  it should goto the root view for that vc, but it doesn't... Is the bannerview delagate (ios 5.0 vc container)  or tabbar delegate screwing this up?

Comment: Right before the pop nslog says viewController is BannerViewController and viewController.navigationController is null. Do I have to put the pop in the for tabitem loop? or change the delagate from bannerview somehow?

Comment: Try calling popToRootViewController on BannerViewController.

Comment: That didnt work either, I dont know how to get access to the delegate navbar. I think the following is kinda what I want but I dont know how to make it work... MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UINavigationController *navController = [appDelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexOfNavController];
[navController popToRootViewController:NO];

Comment: I duno, Ima noob and struggling :/ Heres the nslogs, cant find the nav and pop it, or howto step by step drill down thru my appdelagate :/

ViewController = BannerViewController:

tabBarController = UITabBarController:

tabBarControllerViewController = (
 "BannerViewController: 0x867f450", 
 "BannerViewController: 0x83c58d0", 
 "BannerViewController: 0x83c7b40",
 "BannerViewController: 0x83c9c90")

navController = (null)

Comment: My nslogs work fine when i click the tabitems, i just dont understand howto get: The navbar - inside a tabbar delegate - inside a bannerview delegate vc array...

Answer (score 0):

If you want navigationController in your tabBar then you have to add yourNavigationController instead of viewController.
So in your case you are not adding navigationControllers to your tabBarControllers array.

```
[viewControllers addObject:bannervcs];
```

so instead of adding `bannervcs` add `newsNavigationController`

```
[viewControllers addObject:newsNavigationController];
```

For more info just read and take sample code from [UITabBarController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Soo.... wrap the table in a banner and wrap the banner/table in a Nav? Put the nav on top on the banner? instead of inside the banner?

Comment: first tell me the flow of your problem....what is NewsListViewController? what is BannerViewController?

Comment: The problem is my tabbar doesnt pop to root nav on click like a tabbar app should. I have a table view (newscontroller), wrapped in a Nav(newsnavcontroller), wrapped in the iAd suite container controller(bannervcs), wrapped in a tab bar. The problem is, iAd must wrap the nav/table to keep the ad on top. So the tabbar sees banner containers, not nav containers... If I wrap the table in the banner instead of nav, the ad doesnt stay on top.

Comment: Ok, forget about the nav for a sec... All I want is for the damn tabbar to reload the VC everytime the tabbar is clicked. How do I do that if the VC array is full of Banner VC Containers?

Comment: where are you using [self.navigationControllr pushviewController:...]

Comment: you can reload your tabBarView by using -(void)viewWillAppear:.. method instead of -(void)viewDidLoad